# I want to check the with if column is starting with Alphabet-Numeric-Alphabet (ABC45648DE)

Tags: awk

I want to check the with if column is starting with Alphabet-Numeric-Alphabet (ABC45648DE)

**My input:**

```
ABC45648DEF    |GHJKK    |23132331331|   
ABC     DEF    |GHJKK    |23132331331| 
ABCGHHJJDEF    |GHJKK    |23132331331|
ABC89043DEF    |GHJKK    |23132331331|
```

**Output Should be:**

```
ABC45648DEF    |GHJKK    |23132331331|
ABC89043DEF    |GHJKK    |23132331331|
```

I tried to use this """**awk -F '|' '($1 !~ /[A-Z0-9a-z]/)' WHTFile.txt > QC2Valid.txt**""" it’s not working.

Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you surround your `awk` code with 3 pair dbl-quotes? Use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. Good luck.

Comment: AND please include your current sample output. Otherwise your asking *N* readers to create your test file and run the code, just to see what you mean by "it's not working" . Good luck.

Comment: AND `[A-Z0-9a-z]` means if any single char in `$1` matches that pattern, then the test is passed. I don't think that is what you mean AND given that your `$1` value has trailing spaces this complicates writing a regex to validate your data (or is that a tab char preceding the `|` char?). Good luck.

Comment: AND you expect the `ABCGHHJJDEF` record to fail, so you really want that $1 Must contain A-Za-z AND 0-9 whereas `[A-Z0-9a-z]` implies "as long as any of these exist, (not necessarily all) it is ok". Can you update your Q to have a clear definition of your problem? Thanks and good luck.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me.

Actually it's 3 pair double-quotes I just want highlight that one. This what I am using --> awk -F '|' '($1 !~ /[A-Z0-9a-z]/)' WHTFile.txt > QC2Valid.txt.

The First column should be in starting with ABC -->ABC#####DEF and end with DEF, and it should also contain numbers in between them.

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]]*\\|' '$1~/^ABC[0-9]+DEF/' WHTFile.txt
```

The output:

```
ABC45648DEF    |GHJKK    |23132331331|   
ABC89043DEF    |GHJKK    |23132331331|
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution buddy.

It should start with ABC and end DEF --> ABC######DEF. can you help me here please?

Answer (score 0):

This solution works:

```
awk '/^ABC[0-9]{5}DEF /' WHTFile.txt > QC2Valid.txt
```

It matches "ABCxxxxxDEF " at the start of each line, where "x" is a number.

If any number of digits is needed (and at least 1), this is the script:

```
awk '/^ABC[0-9]+DEF /' WHTFile.txt > QC2Valid.txt
```

The plus sign matches 1 or more digits in the example.

If numbers are optional between ABC and DEF, try this other one:

```
awk '/^ABC[0-9]*DEF /' WHTFile.txt > QC2Valid.txt
```

The asterisk matches zero or more digits in this case.

Comment: Yes, it's working. Thank you much, but numbers in between may not be 5, it can also be less than OR more than that.

awk '/^ABC[0-9]{5}DEF /' WHTFile.txt > QC2Valid.txt

Comment: What happens if you change it to: awk '$1 ~/^ABC[0-9]+DEF$/' file

Comment: @kris I edited my answer to achieve any number of digits (a minimum of 1 digit is matched).